# Cassandra query performs differently at different times

Tags: cassandra

I am using apache-cassandra-2.0.12 in production, with network topology strategy and ReplicationFactor : 3 in a cluster with  2 DC’s each contains 4 nodes

While analyzing the response time for the read requests, we found out that some queries are performing slower than it actually does. 
Eg : Consider the following table

```
Create ColumnFamily "Employee"
(
  empID bigint,
  uniqueID text,
  col1 text,
  col2 text,
  col3 text,
  primary key (empID,uniqueID)
)
```

This CF contains data for more that 5K row entires and and each employee contains minimum of 100K columns and the maximum of 1000K columns

So in this CF the response time for the following queries differs drastically from time to time

```
SELECT * form "Employee" where empID = xxx and uniqueID = 'value';
```

Some times the response time for the above query is more than 3 sec, whereas it should actually take within 50 milliseconds

I have monitored the load (compaction time, disk utilizations etc ), CPU and the memory of the nodes at that time . All these params were normal.

Is there anything that I have missed or is this the normal behavior of cassandra ?

Note: I don't have any tombstone columns in this CF

Comment: Your Table does not match your key. Could you update it with the correct schema?

Comment: What consistency level is used for your reads?

Comment: @Castaglia I am using local_quorum to read the data .

Comment: Try with `TRACING ON`

Comment: @Undefined_variable have tried it. Everything is quite normal

Comment: GC or compaction can affect your response times, because they are i/o intensive

Comment: @LHWizard  Crossed check all the params like GC, Compaction status, CPU Load , Number of queries requested at that time, partition size of the slow query. All these values are usual. ( Repair process was also not initiated at the slow query time )

Comment: I was thinking that since your slowness happens only occasionally, it might be when one of the nodes is doing a GC. I've seen GC kill the response time for a query, then when it's over, responses go back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

```
primary key (empID,uniqueID)
```

> This CF contains data for more that 5K row entires and and each employee contains minimum of 100K columns and the maximum of 1000K columns

That's WAY too many rows per partition.  My guess is that the query slowdowns happen when large partitions are queried.  It all depends on data cell value size and data width, but as a general rule, I would not model more than 10k-30k rows per partition.

To test this out, you could run `nodetool tablehistorgrams` on your table to gauge things like max cell count and partition size.  Then run your query against both small and large partitions with `TRACING ON`, and I'm sure you'll see the difference.

Basically, try reworking your model for smaller partitions.

Answer (score 0):

If it hits the data node as master node, and search is only the other 2 nodes, so response time is lower.
If a request hits the non data node as master node, it needs to get data from 3 nodes in case of a replication factor of 3, so response time will be higher.

CL=local_quorum

Comment: First of all, there is no "master" node in Cassandra.  Secondly, querying at LOCAL_QUORUM with a RF of 3 will pull data from 2 nodes, *not* 3.